# How to include a specific Rails method (or file) in a non-Rails Ruby project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use the `distance_of_time_in_words` method in the date_helper.rb Rails file (see on [Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bd8a9701c27b4261e9d8dd84aebbde6ba784ed83/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L67)) in an non-Rails Ruby project.

How can I include it? It requires other files, so how to include them?

I don't want to include all of Rails because that would slow down the development process.

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method, `distance_of_time_in_words` is in `actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb`. So you should `require 'action_view'` and `action_view/helpers` to load this method. And the method is defined in module `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`, you can include it in your class. The method is an instance method.

```
require 'action_view'
require 'action_view/helpers'

class Klass
    include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
end

c = Klass.new
c.distance_of_time_in_words( ...... )
```

Comment: That's very helpful. I think the best answer is to include the required files without including Rails. But I gather that your answer uses the Rails gem.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only thing you want from it, then I'd just go take the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bd8a9701c27b4261e9d8dd84aebbde6ba784ed83/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L67) and hack it to remove the dependencies (which appears to just be some I18n translations. To support the hack, you can probably translate [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bd8a9701c27b4261e9d8dd84aebbde6ba784ed83/actionpack/test/template/date_helper_test.rb#L21) test suite.

Why would I do this instead of using the gem? Because it's just such an enormous dependency. It's so enormous that you actually notice it loading all that code. I'd rather rip out the method and hack it to work than depend on all of that (again, assuming this is the only thing you want from the lib).

Comment: That probably makes sense in this case because if is easy to remove the dependencies. But in general it might be more practical to include the required files.